# How to assert arrays intersection using chai.js?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I don't like my code here, is there a proper way to find intersection in chai, using similar approach as in finding a superset: `expect([1,2]).to.contain.members([2])`?

```js
mocha.setup("bdd");

var intersection = function(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(function(n) {
    return arr2.indexOf(n) != -1;
  });
};

describe("Test suite", function() {
    it("should find if arrays intersect", function() {
        chai.expect(intersection([1, 2], [2, 3])).not.to.be.empty;
    });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.min.js"></script>

<div id="mocha"></div>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Amit how to assert array intersections using Chai...?

Comment: Which the code in OP *does*. So... What's the question?

Comment: The intersection itself isn't determined by Chai, the question is if it's possible to do so.

Comment: @Amit usually there is always a builtin functionality in chai. I decided to ask here before suggesting PR for the Chai project.

Comment: Personally I don't see it as a core functionality of an assertion library, but if course you can suggest it and let the Chai people decide. Alternatively you can use the plugin API to package this in a more fluent style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chai can do that!

#### New Syntax

```js
expect([1,2]).to.contain.oneOf([2,3]);
```

#### Old Syntax

```js
expect([1,2]).to.include.any.members([2,3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense, I don't now how I've missed that! (Not that I use chai anymore...)

Comment: this does not work for me... maybe this is no longer true?

Comment: In current version of chai it is: to.contain.oneOf

Answer (score 0):

To check for intersection of two arrays, I will suggest you use a set operation library. Hey, I just happened to have written one! It's called affinity, it's free. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/affinity). It is a library for set and relation operators. It's still in development, but set operators work very well (there's 400 unit tests and counting).

In this case, you would want to do

```
var affinity = require('affinity');
var set1 = new affinity.Set({type : affinity.Integer, elements : [1, 2]});
var set2 = new affinity.Set({type : affinity.Integer, elements : [2, 3]});
chai.expect(set1.setIntersection(set2).elements()).not.to.be.empty;

// you also have setUnion, setProduct, ...
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest using `lodash` or `underscore`, might as well mention `_.intersection()` ;D

Comment: Yeah of course! But this library offers much more than _.intersection ! It's based on lodash though.

Comment: I feel that it might be overkill though, given what the actual question tries to accomplish.

Comment: install it with npm, check in the docs folder and open the index.html file, you'll see what it's capable of !

Comment: Yes indeed. It's overkill.

Comment: But for example this library could tell you if a set is a subset / proper subset / superset / proper superset of another set, etc. Those are operators not commonly present in other libraries such as lodash or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.intersection` from the popular [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) library, like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

...

```
chai.expect(_.intersection([1, 2], [2, 3])).not.to.be.empty
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm using, but the question was about a builtin chai functionality of asserting, not finding the result of intersecting